# Unexpected token in a sql query (Hibernate)

Tags: sql, hibernate-spatial

I have no more idea in how to run this query:

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc)::text
FROM (SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type,
ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(lg.geom,4326))\\:\\:json As geometry,
(
select row_to_json(t)
from (select comune) t
)
As properties
FROM comuni_2015 As lg WHERE id >= 0 ) As f )  As fc LIMIT 10
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
return (Geomcomuni) getSession().createQuery(query);
                  "SELECT row_to_json(fc)::text \n" +
                  "FROM (SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features \n" +
                  "FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type, \n" +
                  "ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(lg.geom,4326))::json As geometry, \n" +
                  "(\n"+
                  "select row_to_json(t) \n" +
                  "from (select comune) t \n"+
                  ")\n" +
                  "As properties \n" +
                  "FROM springgis As lg WHERE id >= 0 ) As f )  As fc LIMIT 10");
```

but it gives me this error:

> line 1:23: unexpected token: ":"

have you some suggestion to give me? or some other way..